# Setting Report date parameters

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a report written in visual studio running on a SQL server 2005 DB. 
I want it to automatically apply the day before's date
- start at 00:00:00 and end 23:59:59

From my pic the code I use is
=DateAdd(Dateinterval.day, -1, Now()) for the start date

and for end date I use 
=Now()

These values get me a report for the last 24 hours but I want to get the report to run just for the 24 hours of the previous day. How would I do this?

[image: Report params dates]

Comment: The actual question isn't entirely clear to me. What do "automatically apply" and "get it going" mean in this context? Can you *edit the question* and clarify what you're trying to achieve, and why it's not working?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using `Today()` instead of `Now()`.

Both will give today's date, but `Today()` will not include any time portion.

Comment: So if I want yesterday Can I say today()-1 ?

Comment: Essentially yes, but you'll still need to use DateAdd(), i.e. "=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Today())".

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one date paramater being yesterday `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Today())`.

Then to use this your data should be truncated to the date only and filtered to equal this parameter getting yesterday only irrispective of the time.